# Run Django with gettext without database

Tags: python, django, gettext, django-i18n

I've got a simple webform created with Django 1.6 without using a database backend, as I just don't need them. Now I want to make usage of gettext for some i18n, but I'm getting a

```
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Is their any way to don't make usage of any or should I really configure sqlite at minimum?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are restricted to django for this project? If you're not using the database backend at all then you might consider using Flask or Pyramid (two much more lightweight python-based web frameworks) instead

Comment: No real reason. But I assume at some point there will needs to be a database in background.

Comment: Sounds like that time is now :) You could just use a simple sqlite3 db for now.

Comment: puh.... hmmmm.... well... Going to configure some and hoping there is another good idea in the meanwhile ;)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this article http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2011/01/07/django-micro-framework/ It was written in russian, but from code you can see the main goal.

Comment: There's an English version for this link: http://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2011/01/07/django-micro-framework/en/